# How can I build a modular command-line interface using rubygems?

Tags: ruby, plugins, command-line-interface, organization

I've written a command-line tool for [manipulating with genome scaffolds called "Scaffolder"](https://github.com/michaelbarton/scaffolder-tools). At the moment all the tools I want to use are hard-coded into the library. For instance these tools "validate" or "build" the scaffold. I'd like to split these tools out into their own gems, make it more modular, and to allow third parties to write their own commands.

The ideal case would be that I run "gem install scaffolder-validate" and this gem-bundled command would then be available as part of scaffolder. I know a couple of libraries make it easy to build a command-line interface: thor, commander, gli, .... However I don't think any of them cater for this type of functionality.

My question is how can I use a gem structure to create a module structure for installing these commands? Specifically how can the installed commands be auto-detected and loaded? With some prefix in the gem name scaffolder-* then searching rubygems? How could I test this with cucumber?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking.  Do you want to create a command-line tool that then detects if certain "plugins" are installed and, for each one that's installed, surface that plugin as a feature/option of the command-line app?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do. Ideally I'd like to use ruby gems to manage the plugins rather than roll my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one thing you can do is to decide on a canonical name for your plugins, and then use that convention to load things dynamically.

It looks like your code is all under a module `Scaffolder`, so you can create plugins following the following rules:

- `Scaffolder` gems must be named `scaffold-tools-plugin-`*pluginname*
- All plugins expose one class, named `Scaffolder::Plugin::`*Pluginname*
- That class must conform to some interface you document, and possibly provide a base class for

Given that, you can then accept a command-line argument of the plugins to load (assuming `OptionParser`):

```
plugin_names = []
opts.on('--plugins PLUGINS','List of plugins') do |plug|
  plugin_names << plug
end
```

Then:

```
plugin_classes = []
plugin_names.each do |plugin_name|
  require "scaffold-tools-plugin-#{plugin_name}"
  plugin_classes << Kernel.const_get("Scaffold::Plugin::#{plugin_name}")
end
```

Now `plugin_classes` is an `Array` of the class objects for the plugins configured.  Supposing they all conform to some common constructor and some common methods:

```
plugin_classes.each do |plugin_class|
  plugin = plugin_class.new(args)
  plugin.do_its_thing(other,args)
end
```

Obviously, when doing a lot of dynamic class loading like this, you need to be careful and trust the code that you are running.  I'm assuming for such a small domain, it won't be a concern, but just be wary of `require`ing random code.

Comment: That should work, thank you. I think I'll try to specify the plugins in a scaffolder specific gemfile. That way the versions of plugins can be managed.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, tricky one. One simple idea I have is that the main gem just tries to `require` all the others and catches the load error when they are not there and disables the respective features. I do this in one of my gems. If [HighLine](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/) is present, the user gets prompted for a password, if it isn't there has to be a config file.

```
begin
  require 'highline'
rescue LoadError
  highline = false
end
```

If you have a lot of gems this could become ugly though...

Comment: I think this would make it difficult for third-party developers to write plugins. I would have to update the code with a require statement for each library.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know if only you would develop `scafold-*` commands.

Comment: I was thinking there might be some way in rubygems to search for all gems beginning with the scaffold- prefix. This would allow other parties to develop gems as well.

Comment: Perhaps another option would be have a ~/.scaffolder file in the home directory. This would actually be a bundler file and I could then perhaps 'require' all the gems specified in this file. What do you think?

Comment: I think I prefer the `./scaffolder` option, there's no guarantee someone else won't create a gem named `scaffolder-something`, even it's unlikely.

Comment: I think you're right. Do you have any idea which CLI framework would be the best for modularity? E.g. importing classes with commands? Thor seems to have the cleanest syntax but is a little more restrictive.

Comment: I'd probably go with Thor. You know the good old YAGNI (you ain't gonna need it) rule? If you like Thor's syntax and it can handle what you need it for now, go with it. BTW: this discussion is getting long, that's not what SO comments are for. My Twitter is on my profile if you want to continue this discussion. :-)